# I m trying to work on this update query

Tags: sql

I m trying to work on this update query please help
its not working

```
UPDATE Country set Country.CountryName = 'Swizz' 
from Country,Customers
where Customers.CustomerName='sameer'
```

Comment: and this is SQL Server?

Comment: How is it not working?  Don't be shy.

Comment: the join criteria is missing

Answer (score 1):

for SQL Server and a bit of tidy up

```
UPDATE C 
  set CountryName = 'Swizz' 
from Country C
Inner join Customers x 
  on x.country_code = C.country_code   --- missing component from OP
where x.CustomerName='sameer'
```